# Red boxes around hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref

I am getting red boxes around hyperlinks on the PDF output. Apparently contrary to [this question](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=16708) the boxes are actually part of the final PDF, as when I save a copy of the PDF the red boxes remain.

I think the problem is coming from the only error I get on build:

```
! Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option 'hypertex'
```

which I believe has been produced since changing from LaTeX>>DVI to LaTeX>>PDF

Using TeXnic Center and the following packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[hypertex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\star$}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Add the `colorlinks` option to `hyperref` and check over [the LaTeX Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization).

Comment: And, as before, it's always best to include a minimal working example.

Comment: Skip that option for loading `hyperref`.  And load `hyperref` later on: see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/8528).

Comment: Though this statement doesn't contain a question, the link to the mentioned question may help. Please write in form of a question if you have one, not just like "I'm getting something." - which may be normal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The red boxes are link annotations that are part of the final PDF file, of course. But they are not part of the page description and they are usually not printed (sometimes configurable).

The documentation of `hyperref` lists many options regarding the visual appearance of the links, e.g.:

- `colorlinks`: Instead of the boxes, the contents is colored, but this color
  is part of the page description and is always printed.
- `linkcolor` and friends set the color for the link types and option `colorlinks`.
- `linkbordercolor` and friends set the link border color for the different link types.
- `hidelinks`: the reader does not see any link markings.

If you compile the document with `pdflatex`, then the correct driver option is `pdftex`. DVI driver options like `hypertex` are wrong in this case. Thus the error message is correct. Some drivers are detected automatically, e.g.:

- pdfTeX/luaTeX in PDF mode
- XeTeX
- VTeX

The DVI driver is a program that runs *after* LaTeX, therefore `hyperref` cannot know the driver. It uses (will use) `dvips` as default driver option.
If you prefer `hypertex` in this case, then you can also use

```
\usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref}
```

However, the link appearance cannot be set by hyperref, because the hypertex specials can only say, where is a link. The appearance depends on the viewer/dvi driver.

Comment: Answer  `\usepackage[driverfallback=hypertex]{hyperref}` To remove build error and, from comment on linked question, `\documentclass[hidelinks,12pt]{report}` And thus adding the necessary parameter as a global option to the `\documentclass` declaration.