# Frames around hyperlinks in apa7 documents

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink, apa7

I noticed that when creating documents in the `apa7` document style, the resulting PDF will have colored boxes around the hyperlinks (with colors apparently varying depending on what it's linked to: red for tables, turquoise for web addresses, green for citations).

I tried adding the line `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`, but it only returns:

> Option clash for package hyperref.

How can I remove the frames?

Least working example:

```latex
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % Tried adding this line, but renders an error.

\title{Least working example using the \textsf{apa7} Package}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
We begin with \textcite{Shotton1989}.  We can also cite this work in
parenthesis, like this: \parencite{Shotton1989}.

Table \ref{tab:ComplexTable} contains some sample data.  Our
statistical prowess in analyzing these data is unmatched.

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption{A Complex Table}
    \label{tab:ComplexTable}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lrrr@{}}         \toprule
    Distribution type  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Percentage of} & Total number 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```latex
% Citation
@BOOK{Shotton1989,
  author = {Shotton, Margaret A.},
  title = {Computer addiction? {A} study of computer dependency},
  publisher = {Taylor \& Francis},
  year = {1989},
  location = {London, England}
}
```

Comment: As hyperref is already loaded you can use `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`

Comment: You won't need to pass the options `sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,` to `biblatex`. In fact `sorting=nyt,` will select a slightly different sorting scheme than `style=apa,`'s default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{hidelinks}{hyperref}
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % 
...
```

Comment: That works. I also realized I can set [`hidelinks` in class options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126099/202807): `\documentclass[jou, hidelinks]{apa7}`.

Comment: _All_ class options are also seen by every package and used if it belongs to the package.